# Javascript object text/html automatically redirects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my webpage i have created a little `div` that contains an external site. My code looks like this:

```
    var divPrev = createElement('div', 'divPrev', 'divPrevcss');
    var objSf = createElement('object', 'objSf', 'objSfcss');
    objSf.setAttribute('type','text/html');
    objSf.setAttribute('data','http://'+oStxt.value);
    divPrev.appendChild(objSf);

    divMain.appendChild(divPrev);
```

I use this like a preview and it works with most of the websites, but with some, when the site loads into my div, after a few seconds it loads the site instead of my page, as if redirecting the browser.

An example is if I show into my div http://www.salomon.com.

How is possible prevent this type of behavior?

Comment: Are you using an iFrame to show the preview? A lot of sites have code that prevents them from loading in an iFrame. Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: No iframe just a div containing an object (objSf)

Comment: an object create with createelement('object'

Comment: The `<object>` tag is used for running some sort of external code requiring a plugin - like flash or java.

Comment: Is possible to check if a website have code to prevent loading into an iframe?

Comment: Yes. You can look at the headers the server sends when you get the page and then you've got to look at all the JS and HTML you get to see if they're trying to escape from an iframe there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `<IFRAME>` to embed an other HTML document into your webpage. It has full cross-browser support.